# In Scheme, how do I save records (srfi-9) to a file (serialize them to the file), and read them back in again?

Tags: serialization, scheme, record

Running Guile I'm getting this error: In procedure scm_lreadr: savefile-dev.scm:1:4: Unknown # object: #\<

I believe this is because Scheme's reader can't understand how to read custom records I've created. My goal is to create a bunch of records, save them to a file somehow, and then reconstitute that data structure. Googling around 'data serialization scheme' has not proven helpful.

Here is example code from a task list manager I'm building that demonstrates the issue:

```scm
(import (srfi srfi-9))

(define-record-type task
  (make-task title action-context)
  task?
  (title title set-title!)
  (action-context action-context set-action-context!))

(define savefile-filename "savefile-dev.scm")
(define (load-data)
  (define in (open-input-file savefile-filename))
  (set! tasks (read in))
  (close-port in)) ;; guile

(define (save-data)
  (define out (open-output-file savefile-filename))
  (write tasks out)
  (close-port out)) ;; guile

(define tasks
  (list 
   (make-task "Test task for example purposes." "computer")))
(save-data)
(load-data)
```

I'm open to answers that point me in other directions, again my goal is just: build a basic data structure, save that to a file, and recreate that same data structure from a file so that I can create it one day, and do more with it the next, as users (me) interact with my program.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard serialization format for custom objects, you'll need to devise your own format and parser.

Comment: srfi-10?
https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-10/srfi-10.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/SRFI_002d10.html